# How to convert OSM relation XML data to shapefile?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I would like to transform the XML data here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Berlin/Transportation into shapefiles or load into PostGIS.

I think the thing I am missing is how these XML files, which contains relations, can be used to get the data they represent.

I have tried opening the JOSM link, opening the GPX files in QGIS, and directing to the XML file to osm2shp.jar - none of these routes has given me what I need.  The GPX files can be used to generate a shapefile, but when I 'Open Attributes Table' in QGIS all of the column values are NULL for all points.

I would appreciate a step by step description of how to work with this data in PostGIS or as a shapefile.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do the GPX thing, so this might not help, but have you tried osm2pgsql - http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql ?

Comment: why this is closed? This is a legitimate and common question. I see this question asked all over the web, but it is hard to find clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

On the wiki page, follow the gpx link to get a gpx file. In Quantum GIS, use `Add Vector layer` and select route, or the GPS Tool to add the data to QGIS.

Once it works, you can `Save As` into a shapefile or by copy and paste into an existing postgis layer.

Comment: The problem I find with this, is that the GPX file doesn't contain any contextual information about the points or lines - so I end up with a bunch of points in postGIS but no information about what the points are. That is to say, when I 'Open Attributes Table' every column is NULL.   Have you experienced a different outcome?

Comment: By selecting "routes", you should get lines, not points. And the line number is in the name field. Station points and names are not included. That needs some preprocessing; even osm2pgsql does not do that.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a start at clearing things up.  Oddly, the 'routes' gpx for this particular XML contains only 1 entry which combines all the subway lines and connects their endpoints with straight diagonal lines across the map.  Is that normal for OSM data?

Comment: I realized I should also follow up and say that the route_points GPX is the one the contains all NULL values for every column, and this is where I would have expected to see some kind of station information.

Comment: For your purpose, tracks would be better, but the service does not offer that. If you want full access to the data, you can store a Berlin extract into a postgis database with osm2pgsql or osmosis. But it still needs some handwork afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Andre, that's what I'm starting to understand.  I will post a complete exploration of what I've learned once I've made it all the way through.